# MouseAdapter not working

Tags: java, mouselistener, ubuntu-15.04

I have a problem with java 7/8 under Ubuntu 15.04. I participate on a project, that's been up for 4 years now, so fixing things in there might be a bigger problem. Nevertheless: When I started using Ubuntu 15.04 the MouseListener stopped working. I minimized the problem to make clear, what I mean:

```
public class MenuGui {
    public MenuGui() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu m1 = new JMenu("Start");
        JMenuItem i11 = new JMenuItem("Action");


        i11.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "hi");
            }

        });
        m1.add(i11);
        bar.add(m1);
        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MenuGui();
    }
}
```

When I run this example on my machine, the Menu is on the gnome menu, but clicking the Menu Entry does not do anything. Question now is: is there a way to easily place the menu back to the actual jframe or even better is there a fix for ubuntu 15.04?
Running it as root places the menu back to the jframe and it starts working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without being an expert on JMenuItems, I think you need an ActionListener, NOT listen to mouse events.

Comment: Yes, that's something that surprised me too, but like I said, it's a bigger project, I don't want to rewrite the whole code ;)